# implementar un modalen angular con fullcandelar

Tags: angular

estoy tratando de implementar un  candelar de  reservas,  el  objetivo  en  si  es  que  al  momento de  dar  click  sobre  un evento  este me lance más  información  en  un modal  que  se  habrá,  esto lo estoy haciendo con fullcandelar. pero al  momento de mandar  llamar  función  que  abrira el modal no me reconoce, mi función dejo mi código. espero alguien me apoye  saludos  y gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

este  es  mi código en mi app.js

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
      listPlugin,    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    events : this.bookings,
     eventClick:function(info){
      this.openmodal()
     },
    };


  public activeDayIsOpen: boolean = true;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRentalDays()
  }

getRentalDays() {
    this.rentalService.getNotCancelledRentalsByCompanyID(this.currentUser.currentUser.companyId).subscribe(rentals =>{
      let data  = rentals;

    this.bookings = data.map((rental) =>{
      //formart  date
     let reservedDate = moment(rental.statusDate.isReserved.toDate()).format('MMMM Do YYYY');       let productsName = '';
     let totalValue = 0;       //  if  productos  length  is    elderly  than  1,
     if (rental.products.length > 1) {
       rental.products.forEach(product => {
         productsName += product.productName + ' ' + product.productSize + ', ';         });
     } else {
       productsName = rental.products[0].productName + ' ' + rental.products[0].productSize + '';       }
     rental.products.forEach(product => {
       totalValue += product.subtotal;
     });       let date = "";
     let dayStart;
     let dayEnd;
     if (rental.rentalType == "byHour") {
       dayStart = moment(rental.dayStart.seconds * 1000).format('MMM DD YYYY, h:mm a');
       dayEnd = moment(rental.dayEnd.seconds * 1000).format('h:mm a');
       date = " - " + dayStart + " - " + dayEnd;
       console.log(date);
     }
     let eventObj: CustomCalendarEvent = {
       start: new Date(rental.dayStart.seconds * 1000),
       end: new Date(rental.dayEnd.seconds * 1000),
       title: 'Name: ' + rental.userInfo.name +  '| Rental Number: ' + rental.rentalNumber,
       obj: rental,
       total : totalValue
      }
      return eventObj;

        });

         this.calendarOptions.events = this.bookings;
         this.refresh.next();

    });

  }

  openmodal(){

  this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });

  }
```